# symfony2.3 filter twig inside other filter

Tags: symfony, twig

i have filter in twig :

```
class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('price', array($this, 'priceFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function priceFilter($number, $decimals = 0, $decPoint = '.', $thousandsSep = ',')
    {
        $price = number_format($number, $decimals, $decPoint, $thousandsSep);
        $price = '$'.$price;

        return $price;
    }
}
```

but how can call price filter inside other filter? in symfony 2.0 declared filter with  `'price' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'priceFilter')`

and could from within another filter call this.

thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want the returned value of the other filter into your price filter, you can chain them in twig:

```
{{ value|acme_filter|price }}
```

Or in the other direction, if you need the return value of the price filter in your other filter:

```
{{ value|price|acme_filter }}
```

If you really need the price filter inside your other filter, no problem. The extension is a plain php class.

```
public function acmeFilter($whatever)
{
    // do something with $whatever

    $priceExtentsion = new PriceExtenstion();
    $whatever = $priceExtension->priceFilter($whatever);

    // do something with $whatever

    return $whatever;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class SomeExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    function getName() {
        return 'some_extension';
    }

    function getFilters() {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter(
                'filterOne',
                function(\Twig_Environment $env, $input) {
                    $output = dosmth($input);
                    $filter2Func = $env->getFilter('filterTwo')->getCallable();
                    $output = call_user_func($filter2Func, $output);
                    return $output;
                },
                ['needs_environment' => true]
            ),
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter(
                'filterTwo',
                function ($input) {
                    $output = dosmth($input);
                    return $output;
                }
            )
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use callback function as "static".

You can define your function as static, or replace to \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'priceFilter')